# wlst hangs intermittently in ServerRuntime()

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, wlst

I am observing the below behavior while running any command for my managed instances:

wls:/application/domainRuntime/ServerRuntimes/MS015> ls()

this command hangs indefinitely. no operations will work here. IT just displays the directories and hangs while displaying other Mbeans. It also needs to display other Mbeans like State,  StateVal, Type etc.
this happens intermittently.

wls:/application/domainRuntime/ServerRuntimes/MS015> ls()

dr--   ApplicationRuntimes

dr--   AsyncReplicationRuntime

dr--   ClusterRuntime

dr--   ConnectorServiceRuntime

dr--   DefaultExecuteQueueRuntime

dr--   EntityCacheCumulativeRuntime

dr--   EntityCacheCurrentStateRuntime

dr--   EntityCacheHistoricalRuntime

dr--   ExecuteQueueRuntimes

dr--   JDBCServiceRuntime

dr--   JMSRuntime

dr--   JTARuntime

dr--   JVMRuntime

dr--   JoltRuntime

dr--   LibraryRuntimes

dr--   LogBroadcasterRuntime

dr--   LogRuntime

dr--   MANAsyncReplicationRuntime

dr--   MANReplicationRuntime

dr--   MailSessionRuntimes

dr--   MaxThreadsConstraintRuntimes

dr--   MessagingBridgeRuntime

dr--   MinThreadsConstraintRuntimes

dr--   PathServiceRuntime

dr--   PersistentStoreRuntimes

dr--   RequestClassRuntimes

dr--   SAFRuntime

dr--   SNMPAgentRuntime

dr--   ServerChannelRuntimes

dr--   ServerSecurityRuntime

dr--   SingleSignOnServicesRuntime

dr--   ThreadPoolRuntime

dr--   TimerRuntime

dr--   WANReplicationRuntime

dr--   WLDFRuntime

dr--   WTCRuntime

dr--   WebServerRuntimes

dr--   WorkManagerRuntimes

dr--   WseeClusterFrontEndRuntime

dr--   WseeWsrmRuntime

Comment: Does the log file for `MS015` indicate anything is wrong with that server?

Comment: No, It just hangs, there is no exception/error in the log. Also the server heapFreePercent is good. It happens randomly on all managed server instances.

Answer (score 0):

It does matter how you are invoking the WLST. If you are using any OARACLE Fusion Middleware products you need to use $WL_HOME/common/bin/wlst.sh by default it uses proper -mx, -ms values for JVM that used by your WLST. If problem still persists write back or raise a Oracle support ticket!

Cheers